# Data processing balance

Tags: java, hibernate, load-balancing

I have a queue with jobs that goes to different executor pools depending on the type of jobs. The queue is in a DB table and contains jobs from different clients with priorities, etc. I'm omitting some details irrelevant to the question.
At some point different clients put many jobs in the queue at the same time with the same priority, for example about 15-20'000 jobs.

With the current implementation, jobs are fetched using hibernate with this criteria and again, I'm omitting some restrictions for simplicity.

```java
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -minutes);

Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(QueueEntry.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("processing", false))
.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.ge("serverTimestamp", cal.getTime()), Restrictions.ge("sentTimestamp", cal.getTime())))
.add(Restrictions.lt("attemps", attemps))
.addOrder(Order.asc("priority"))
.addOrder(Order.asc("serverTimestamp"))
.setMaxResults(limit);
```

In the current situation if client A inserts 15k tasks in 10:00:00 and client B inserts 3k tasks in 10:00:05 (5 seconds later) with the same priority, B's tasks will be fetched and executed after those of A's.

I need to balance fetched jobs between the clients (there's a "client" column in the queue table) - for example if the throughput is 10 tasks/sec to get 5 of the A's tasks and 5 of the B's. When there's no more tasks for client B, to get 10 of A's tasks.

Is there some easy way or trick to do this with the query? The DB is Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to do it by modifying your existing `Criteria` or with just a single query. To prevent client starvation you would have to create separate resource pools for each client, which is the apporach taken by [Fair Scheduler for Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/fair_scheduler.html):

> The fair scheduler organizes jobs into pools, and divides resources fairly between these pools. By default, there is a separate pool for each user, so that each user gets an equal share of the cluster. It is also possible to set a job's pool based on the user's Unix group or any jobconf property. Within each pool, jobs can be scheduled using either fair sharing or first-in-first-out (FIFO) scheduling.

You can run a query to get a list of distinct clients with total number of awaiting jobs. Based on the distinct client count divide the global job limit and fetch the awaiting jobs for each given client in a separate query.